# (Flask) is it good to get form content_length as precheck for security reasons?

Tags: python, flask

in flask [request.get_data()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.get_data) I read the following quoted sentence and it kept me thinking:

> Usually it’s a bad idea to call this method without checking the content length first as a client could send dozens of megabytes or more to cause memory problems on the server.

So my first question, should I check the [**content_length**](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Response.content_length) on every data entry, e.g. sign-in from **?** or is it only for uploaded files?

here is my flask code for sign-in/sign-out page:

```
@app.route('/signing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signing():
    try:
        if current_user.is_anonymous:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                print(request.content_length)
                username = request.form['username']
                password = request.form['password']
                
                user = Authorization.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('home_redirect'))
            else:
                return render_template('pages/signing.html')
        else:
            logout_user()
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    except:
        abort(501)
```

---

the `print(request.content_length)` statement above return **33**.

What does the number **33** represent **?** Could you please convert it to kB, or Bytes to help me understand the significance of that number.

Comment: If you got any comments or some tips to use on the code above that would be helpful as well.

Comment: it means 33 bytes.

Comment: @Bharel thanks. Does that means the posted username and password is 33 bytes, or the whole page is 33 bytes? Thanks for answering in advance.

Comment: It means that the payload size in your POST request is 33 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent memory issues/ denial of service, checking the content-length header can give a representation of bytes of a POST body for an HTTP request. Not using a request with an absurd amount of data would be advised since a client could send a spoofed request with TONS of data that could be very tough for the server to handle. The content-length header is always represented in every valid HTTP request spoofed or from a browser, so it is excellent to utilize. Using that number as an integer and simply checking if it’s greater than a value that would be outlandish but possible such as a few hundred before parsing the response is important.

For more reading, I also suggest you look at [Flask Limiter](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Limiter/) to rate limit your endpoints against clients and users with malicious intent to protect your server's speed and limited resources.